# Spring Data - MongoDB - more terms linked with and

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I use this search method in my Spring data/MongoDB application:

```
 @Query("{$text : { $search : ?0 } }")
List<DocumentFile> findBySearchString(final String searchString);
```

My question would be what I have to give in for searchString that I get DocumentFiles where two terms exists (e.g. term1 AND term2 or term1 + term2).
Is there something like AND with Spring Data and MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve using mongo repository

```
List<DocumentFile> findByString1AndString2(String String1,String String2);
```

Ok, based on your last round of comments-can we do like this

Using mongo template

```
   Criteria regex = Criteria.where("name").regex("*.xxxx.*", "i");
    mongoOperations.find(new Query().addCriteria(regex), DocumentFile.class);
```

Using mongo repository

```
List<DocumentFile> documents= repository .findByQuery(".*ab.*");
interface repository extends MongoRepository<DocumentFile, String> {
     @Query("{'name': {$regex: ?0 }})")
     List<DocumentFile> findByQuery(String name);
}
```

Hope it will useful.

Comment: I mean what the user can give in in order to find term1 AND term2. Thanks!

Comment: i didn't understand what you saying, if you comment your problem properly  i can help you out.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question! Has the user any possibilities with his search input to control if it is a fulltext search, or if it is a "like" search, ...?